# Are there incremental updates to the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've only found the full download (iPhone SDK 3.1.2 with Xcode 3.2.1) on the developer center. I haven't been able to find something that will update me from 3.0 to 3.1.2? If I already have the 3.0 SDK do I still have to download the full 2.5GB version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-download the whole thing for each major update. The installer is smart enough to "patch" your current install to the new version, but there isn't an update-only installer.